# How do I create a block for my heartbeat activity?

Tags: blocks, heartbeat

I have a heartbeat activity and a message template. I'm able to log the activities using `heartbeat_api_log()`, but how do I show the activities in a block?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heartbeat has views integration. Just built a view and add it to a block.